# DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `__getitem__`

Tags: artificial-intelligence, lstm, google-colaboratory, chatbot, seq2seq

I've been trying to solve this error for some days now and I just can't manage to find the cause, I tried changing the cod from  embedding_matrix[ i ] = model[vocab[i]] to  embedding_matrix[ i ] = model.wv[vocab[i]] in which case I don't get the deprecated error but I still get the erorr with that line(25), can someone tell me what is wrong please

```
  from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import re

vocab = []
for word in tokenizer.word_index:
    vocab.append( word )

def tokenize( sentences ):
    tokens_list = []
    vocabulary = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        sentence = sentence.lower()
        sentence = re.sub( '[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sentence )
        tokens = sentence.split()
        vocabulary += tokens
        tokens_list.append( tokens )
    return tokens_list , vocabulary

p = tokenize( questions + answers )
model = Word2Vec( p[ 0 ] ) 

embedding_matrix = np.zeros( ( VOCAB_SIZE , 100 ) )
for i in range( len( tokenizer.word_index ) ):
    embedding_matrix[ i ] = model[vocab[i]]

# encoder_input_data
tokenized_questions = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences( questions )
maxlen_questions = max( [ len(x) for x in tokenized_questions ] )
padded_questions = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences( tokenized_questions , maxlen=maxlen_questions , padding='post' )
encoder_input_data = np.array( padded_questions )
print( encoder_input_data.shape , maxlen_questions )
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:25: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `__getitem__` (Method will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.wv.__getitem__() instead).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-29183abd3d2d> in <module>()
     23 embedding_matrix = np.zeros( ( VOCAB_SIZE , 100 ) )
     24 for i in range( len( tokenizer.word_index ) ):
---> 25     embedding_matrix[ i ] = model[vocab[i]]
     26 
     27 # encoder_input_data
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Direct model viewer was depricated in new gensim version, instead it used helper method wv, it is unequivocally this error.
According to the documentation https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html, the trained word vectors are stored in a KeyedVectors instance, as model.wv.
Change code in line 25 on this:

`embedding_matrix[ i ] = model.wv[vocab[i]]`

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for contributing. Code only responses are discouraged as low quality on SO. Please consider editing to add an explanation how/why this solves the OP's issue, or even a link to documentation. Note that most upvotes come from quality answers over time, as various users learn something from your post to apply to their own coding issues.

Comment: Thank you ! added description and useful information